# is it possible to create a twitter icon below tweet

Tags: twitter

I am just wondering if it is possible for a twitter app to add an app button to a tweet. for instance I notice that below a tweet I find a Buffer icon along with the reply and retweet buttons. Buffer is not part of twitter but somehow they have added a buffer button to the tweet that you can click to schedule posts. Does anyone know if this was something that Buffer managed to develop with special twitter support or if other developers can also add their own clickable icons to tweet posts.

Cheers

Dave

Comment: the Buffer button is added by the Buffer browser plugin/addon you have installed.

Comment: yes, but how do they do it?

Comment: develop a firefox addon, a chrome extension, similar for Safari, Opera, etc if applicable, and ask your users to install it.

Comment: but what have bowser extensions got to do with what you see under a twitter tweet on twitter, do they really inject the icon into the DOM? I noticed that twitter controls pretty heavily the javascript they allow to run on the page (my bookmark using jqueryui wont run there for instance)

Comment: Yes, the browser extension injects buttons to the DOM. twitter does not control the javascript you decide to run at client side.

Comment: I got some errors related to loading of css pages 
`Refused to load the stylesheet 'data:text/css,@import%20url%28https%3A//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquer…themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css%3Fr1416733530593%3D1416733530593%29%3B' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'unsafe-inline' https:".`  [Here is what twitter say about it](https://twittercommunity.com/t/blocking-mixed-content-with-content-security-policy/26375) maybe Buffer are allowed

Comment: Mef, Could you add the your comment as an answer, then I can accept it. Thanks Dave

Comment: the error you get is caused by the way you're trying to do it. I think you tried to do a bookmarklet, search about how to make it work, plenty of examples on stackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enrich the twitter page or your users, you should build browser extensions, and get your users to install them.

This will let you add whatever content and interactions you want.

You may want to read Google Chrome extensions' [getting started guide](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted).

Answer (score 0):

Those tweets you see with interactive elements are using [Twitter Cards](https://dev.twitter.com/cards/overview).

They're fairly simple to set up - but will require you to add some metadata to your website.